# How to create a two fixed horizontally aligned button at bottom on mobile screens only?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I  create a two fixed horizontally aligned button at bottom on the mobile screens only with the help of css or bootstrap ? I tried it, but it didn't work as expected.

```
<style>
.mobileShow{
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
.mobileShow {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
  }
}
</style>

<div class="mobileShow">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <button class='btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block'>Login</button>
    <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'>Register</button>
</div>
```

Comment: In what way does it not work as expected? At a guess, you might be surprised how dense today's phone screens are.

Comment: i wanted it to be worked on all kinds of mobile in general..

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to use `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`.
Also you are missing a clossing `<div>` at the bottom.

**Html:**

```
<div class="mobileShow">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <button class='btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block'>Login</button>
    <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'>Register</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mobileShow{
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}

.mobileShow .btn.btn-block {
  margin-top: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .mobileShow {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

I have created a working example for you here: https://codepen.io/bj-rn-nyborg/pen/bGwGpzN

Comment: @Yash i have edited the styling now, simply use `display:block;` instead of `display:flex;` :)